# How can I check if all visible inputs have a value? (no jquery validator)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check on click of a button if all visible required fields are selected.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
</div>
<button class="check-fields">Check Fields</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {
 var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
    return this.value === '';
  });
  if (value.length == 0) {alert('Everything has a value.');
  } else if (value.length > 0) {
    alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0pk7cdr/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have one more text field with same class inside hidden div. which always remains empty. You should filter out from visible text elements only:

```
var value = $('.required-entry:visible').filter(function () {
  return this.value === '';
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z0row9j7/)**